# How to tell that 2 set of data are not so difference by using statistical method?

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods

How to find stable point of these data?

```
 2.0, -3.5,  0.0,  1.5
 1.3,  6.3,  0.1, -3.4
 3.3, -1.1,  3.0,  4.1
-2.5,  4.3  -1.0,  2.2
```

The example data is random data(now at time t = 0) which later i put them to some equations and simulate it with time dependent.

As time passes these data will go to either value `0` or `1`

```
1, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 1
1, 1, 1, 0
```

But practically, the data at stable state might be look like this

at time t = 150 (be at stable state already)

```
 1.1,  0.0,  0.0, -0.1
 0.1,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0
-0.2,  0.1, -0.1,  0.9
 1.2,  1.0,  1.1,  0.0
```

at time t = 151 (be at stable state already)

```
 1.0,  0.1, -0.1,  0.0
 0.0,  1.1,  1.1,  0.1
 0.0,  0.1,  0.0,  1.0
 0.9,  1.0,  1.0,  0.1
```

The simulation will take random numbers at `t = 0` go to value either `0` or `1` with small fluctuation (might be `+-0.2` in this case) at stable state

My question is how can i find first time step `t` where my data be in stable state?

Note that what you have for calculation is data at time `t` and at time `t-1` and this is why i label my question as `How to tell that 2 set of data are not so difference by using statistical method?`.

Comment: I think you need to tell us what you mean by 'not so different.' Also, it would help if we knew something more about the process that is changing the numbers. You seem to know when stable state is reached. What is your criterion? Might they diverge again after settling down? Finally, you present data that seem in matrix format. Is matrix structure important? Looks like the stable state may be intended to have a _particular_ pattern of 0s and 1s. There a lot of fantastic mathematicians visiting this site, but very few mind readers.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo 'not so different' means when my data evolve from random number at initial state to stable state which value either 1 or 0 with small fluctuation +-0.2. and after that data will continue move in small fluctuation +-0.2 forever. My point is how to detect when the data go to stable state? note that my data is not matrix but i can plot this data as contour plot using data above with linespace(row) and line space(col).